# checkbox checked change in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i designed website with MVC. I have an check box in page that I want when checked changed,run action and save changes in the database. I used from jquery-ajax ,but not firing.
My view

```
@model TaavonS.Models.PaginatedList<TaavonS.Models.TaavoniInfo>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="TableFormat">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.FlagT, new { @id=item.Scode})
</div>

  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#FlagT").change(function () {
            $.ajax({

                url: '@Url.Action("EditTInfoNamayesh", "manager")',
                type: "POST",
                data: { newValue: $("#FlagT").is(':checked'), id: $("#FlagT").attr('id') }, //data,
                dataType: 'json', //type of response
                success: success
            });
        })
    })
</script>
```

And my controller is:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult EditTInfoNamayesh(int id,bool newValue)
    {
        var model = DBConn.TaavoniInfos.Find(id);
        model.FlagT = newValue;
        TryUpdateModel(model);
        DBConn.SaveChanges();
        return Json(true);
    }
```

please help me
thanks alot

Comment: need i add html.beginform?

Answer (score 0):

Have you check `item.Scode`'s value ? If `item.Scode != "FlagT"`, your js won't trigger anything. This is because when you write `$("#FlagT")`, it looks for an element whose `id = "FlagT"`.

Either make your `id` a constant value, or rely on a constant `class` if you need to set your `id` dynamically, like this :

```
<div class="TableFormat">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.FlagT, new { @id=item.Scode, @class="FlagT"})
</div>

  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".FlagT").change(function () {
            $.ajax({

                url: '@Url.Action("EditTInfoNamayesh", "manager")',
                type: "POST",
                data: { newValue: $(this).is(':checked'), id: $(this).attr('id') }, //data,
                dataType: 'json', //type of response
                success: success
            });
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: In page I can see scode .it has data.but when click on check no firing and not running javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I think `change` event will be for `Dropdownlist`. You need to wire up to the `.click` event handler in case of checkbox checked.

Here is the javascript to modify a little bit.

```
  $("#FlagT").click(function () {

        var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');

        //save to database if the checkbox is checked.
        if(isChecked){

          $.ajax({

            url: '@Url.Action("EditTInfoNamayesh", "manager")',
            type: "POST",
            data: { newValue: $("#FlagT").is(':checked'), id: $("#FlagT").attr('id') }, //data,
            dataType: 'json', //type of response
            success: success
          });
        } else {
          return false;
        }
    });
```

Try this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Raly Can you inspect the checkbox so that you can get the id of the checkbox. Is the id of the checkbox correct ?

Comment: cant run javascript. after click on checkbox nothing do. and not go to the action.

Comment: Is the id correct ? Check your browser console to see if there are any errors

Comment: Check your browser console for any errors by pressing F12. Seems like you have not included jquery library. from the code you posted it seems like you have included validate.js and unobtrusive.js and other. But there is no jquery.js file. try by including the jquery.js file. or add

Answer (score 0):

**1.Id should not be with '@'.**

**2. Language = "Javascript" is deprecated.**

you're using $('#FlagT'), verify in Developer Tools for the Id generated in Runtime. since you are using model name and mentioned 'id' in Html attributes, verify what's the id generated in DOM.

Then it should work. if you still have issues with parameters being passed, just add

```
'traditional:true'
```

to the data post in ajax. It will work.

Comment: where i should put traditional:true

Comment: dataType: 'json', //type of response
    traditional: true, //use it if your parameters are not passed.
    success: success